# Python Tkinter getting values in a series of Entries created in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program where the user selects the size of the matrix through a combobox, creates a number of entries based on the value of the combobox,input values in the created Entry properties. How do I get the values of the Entry that were created in a for loop and then store them in a 2d array. I tried using the winfo_children() on this but it outputs an empty array.

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb
import os

os.environ['TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION'] = '1'

root = tb.Window(themename="solar")  # dark mode
# root = tb.Window(themename="cerculean") # light mode

root.title("RREF CALCULATOR")

root.geometry('1000x800')
root.resizable(False, False)
mytitle = tb.Label(text="Find the RREF of a Matrix from 2x2 to 5x5", font=('helvetica', 29), bootstyle=DEFAULT)

setup = tb.Frame(root, bootstyle=DEFAULT)
setup.place(x=400, y=150)

setupMatrix = tb.Frame(root)
setupMatrix.place(x=150, y=450)

# labels for row and col,
row = tb.Label(setup, text="Enter number of Rows", font=('helvetica', 18), bootstyle=DEFAULT)
col = tb.Label(setup, text="Enter number of Columns", font=('helvetica', 18), bootstyle=DEFAULT)

matrixSize = ["2", "3", "4", "5"]

myButton = tb.Button(setup, text="Create matrix", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: setCol(setupMatrix))
resetButton = tb.Button(setup, text="Reset", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: resetMatrix(setupMatrix, rowCombo, colCombo))
solveButton = tb.Button(root, text="Solve Matrix", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: solveMatrix(setupMatrix))
# dropdowns for the size of the matrix
colCombo = tb.Combobox(setup, bootstyle=DEFAULT, values=matrixSize)
colCombo.current(0)
rowCombo = tb.Combobox(setup, bootstyle=DEFAULT, values=matrixSize)
rowCombo.current(0)

row.pack(pady=5)
rowCombo.pack(pady=5)
col.pack(pady=5)
colCombo.pack(pady=10)
myButton.pack(side=LEFT)
resetButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
mytitle.pack(pady=50)
solveButton.pack(pady=310)

class Table:
    def setCol(self, setupMatrix):
        colSize = int(colCombo.get())
        rowSize = int(rowCombo.get())

        for i in range(rowSize):
            for j in range(colSize):
                entry = Entry(setupMatrix, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
                entry.grid(row=i, column=j)

def setCol(setupMatrix):
    table_instance.setCol(setupMatrix)

def resetMatrix(setupMatrix, rowCombo, colCombo):
    for widget in setupMatrix.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    rowCombo.set('')  # Clear the selected value in the combobox
    colCombo.set('')  # Clear the selected value in the combobox

def solveMatrix(setupMatrix):
    matrix_values = []
    for i in range(len(setupMatrix.winfo_children())):
        row_values = []
        for j in range(len(setupMatrix.winfo_children()[i].winfo_children())):
            entry = setupMatrix.winfo_children()[i].winfo_children()[j]
            value = entry.get()
            row_values.append(value)
        matrix_values.append(row_values)

    # Now matrix_values contains the values of the matrix in a 2D array
    print(matrix_values)

# Create an instance of the Table class
table_instance = Table()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `widget.winfo_children()` returns a 1-D array of its children inside the widget, and may not in the sequence you want.

You can create the 2-D array using

- `.grid_size()` to returns the number of rows and columns
- `.grid_slave(row=row, column=col)` to return the widget at (row, col)

```py
def solveMatrix(setupMatrix):
    cols, rows = setupMatrix.grid_size()
    matrix_values = [[setupMatrix.grid_slaves(row=row, column=col)[0].get()
                         for col in range(cols)] for row in range(rows)]
    # Now matrix_values contains the values of the matrix in a 2D array
    print(matrix_values)
```

Another way is create a 2-D array inside `Table.__init__()` and put those entry boxes into the array.